# Reference parent element in hover declaration without givin specific name to it

Tags: css, reactjs

I have three divs, two are nested into a parent. I would like change the color of children when parent is hovered. Though I would like to do it without assigning a class name to the parent one.

I can't do that in parent because the childrent have color of their own that overrides the parent color and basically nothing happen on hover.

```
  <div
    css={css`
      flex: none;
    `}
  >
    <div
      css={css`
        display: inline;
        color: #ffffff;
        & :parent :hover { // incorrect, need something like this
          color: #ffa040;
        }
      `}
    >
    ...
    </div>
    <div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done through CSS. Let me show an example:

```
.outer:hover .inner {
 background-color: orange;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    1
    <div class="inner ">
    2
    </div>    
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Only div's, without classes:

CSS:

```
div:hover div {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
     1
     <div>
          4
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to do the same without giving `class` values?